# How to store long decimal value in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

What datatype will support to store this long valus in DB2 ex. 2861.260000000000218278728425502777099609375. I have tried with Double and Decimal datatypes but no luck. If its not supported then what is the best option to store such values? Thanks.

Comment: You need a string to store so many decimal digits.

Comment: DB2 has 31 as max decimal precision.

Comment: Store vs. algorithmic operations...?

Comment: Store it as a VARCHAR. Most apps won't be able to treat such a number as a real scalar.

Comment: If you want to make Db2 do some math on such long values, you should use VARCHAR data type to store them and create some external UDF doing math needed. The easiest way is to use a simple JAVA UDF using java.sql.BigDecimal class, which may operate with very long numbers. For example, you may create a scalar function `SUM_BIG (VARCHAR (100), VARCHAR (100))` summing long values like you mentioned and returning the result as VARCHAR (100). You may create even UDAF (user defined aggregate function), but it's easy to do in the latest V11.5 only. I may create an example, if you are interested.